# Tumblr "like-heart-button" script on homepage

Tags: tumblr, social-media-like

How to make a 'like' button for each post without going on permalink page? I mean, even in the homepage, which script can I use to have something like the heart on [this](http://cicerontheme.tumblr.com) page? (mouseover the photos, there's a heart to like the post)

Comment: i'm so sorry but could you please elaborate on the code?
im not sure what words i need to replace and with what. also, I'm confused as to where to place the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the page, they're using the javascript:

```
$('a.like-link').click(function() {
    var post = $(this).closest('.post');
    var id = post.attr('id');
    var oath = post.attr('rel').slice(-8);
    var like = 'http://www.tumblr.com/like/'+oath+'?id='+id;
    $('#likeit').attr('src', like);
}
```

So `post` is just the HTML element of the post, they then simply get the `id` of that post and the 8 char code needed to like or reblog a post. They take all this, throw it into a URL and set it to the source of an iFrame on the page (`#likeit`)

Comment: Thanks for the start, RSully. I found the additional information in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048446/85292) very helpful.

Comment: No longer works with the new like reblog buttons

Answer (score 3):

I've created a tutorial on this at: http://like-button.tumblr.com. It eliminates the problems people have with implementing this and makes it a simple cut and paste.

To add Like functionality, you use the following URL and set it as the `src` attribute of an invisible `<iframe>`:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/<command>/<oauthId>?id=<postId>
```

- `<command>`: `like` or `unlike`
- `<oauthId>`: last eight characters of `{ReblogURL}`
- `<postId>`: `{PostID}`

Example:

```
http://www.tumblr.com/like/fGKvAJgQ?id=16664837215
```

Cut and paste the following code block into your theme immediately before `</head>`. This will give you a Like button on each post that looks like the default Tumblr grey heart. It will turn red when you hover over it and when you click it. If you click it again, it will turn grey again and delete the Like.

Code:

```html
<style>
.my-like {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAARCAYAAAA/mJfHAAABH0lEQVQ4y62T30vCUBiGv/9YuhBLkCA08FdogRFFYFEUhhZNCCQoSESiIOii68pl5qV6s8Eb7+SMHXNs6S7ejZ3zvA+ccT4BICofvS88dJ7w8vqG8WQC754K17lPjrx3z3l8D4YoVaqIrWbcJNbzaHefNZjfXPdy5b0jsO/IRqMxUpmSBnhz2bx1QL79GPbpEePmzhdSyW8fBDL0SK68HwiGCT2S3NiKREaPzP7QRRNPZSHpwm4kMnqkYbQikdEjZv8HK2ubS4nY75mD6WU8qzeXkrHvToBlWSjuHC4kYo99V8bwBnM0/iMiz542myq2bSPskcmR/zPos7lvP8Lv/nGd+/N6c2Xq2KcXhiY6qV1rxwotU3n/NHF8fgW+g9hfsHJlJUYljcgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.my-liked, .my-like:hover {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<iframe id="my-like-frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>' );
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    var myLike = event.target;
    if( myLike.className.indexOf( 'my-like' ) > -1 ) {
        var frame = document.getElementById( 'my-like-frame' ),
            liked = ( myLike.className == 'my-liked' ),
            command = liked ? 'unlike' : 'like',
            reblog = myLike.getAttribute( 'data-reblog' ),
            id = myLike.getAttribute( 'data-id' ),
            oauth = reblog.slice( -8 );
        frame.src = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + id;
        liked ? myLike.className = 'my-like' : myLike.className = 'my-liked';
    };
}, false );
};
</script>
```

Then cut and paste the following button code into your theme where you want your like button to be (this must be inside your `{block:Posts}` block).

Code:

```html
<div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}"></div>
```