# heart (like) button on tumblr homepage

Tags: javascript, html, tumblr

Looking at the various posts here and on google groups on the subject, I'm trying to use the script from the [ciceron theme](http://cicerontheme.tumblr.com/) to reproduce the heart (like) button, but I haven't succeed so far.

Below is my code. Did I miss something? Did someone manage to work it out?

In the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/53unaru/y8wlgzkbt/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$('a.like-link').click(function() {
    var post = $(this).closest('.post');
    var id = post.attr('id');
    var oauth = post.attr('rel').slice(-8);
    var like = 'http://www.tumblr.com/like/'+oauth+'?id='+id;
    $('#likeit').attr('src', like);
    $(this).addClass('liked'); return 
false;}) 

</script>
```

In the CSS part of `<head>`:

```
#likeit {height: 0; width: 0; visibility: hidden;}
```

In the `<body>`:

```
<iframe id="likeit"></iframe>
in {Block:post}:
<a href="#" class="like-link">Like</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated my Tumblr tutorial on this to make it cut and paste: http://like-button.tumblr.com

You're missing the oAuth key. Each post has a unique ID that must be sent to do a Like. You can find it at the end of the `{ReblogURL}` variable (which is undocumented). It's the last eight characters. In your example it's grabbing it from the `rel` attribute on the post:

```js
var oauth = post.attr('rel').slice(-8);
```

Cut and paste the following code block into your theme immediately before `</head>`. This will give you a like button on each post that looks like the default Tumblr grey heart. It will turn red when you hover over it and when you click it. If you click it again, it will turn grey again and delete the Like.

```html
<style>
.my-like {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABMAAAARCAYAAAA/mJfHAAABH0lEQVQ4y62T30vCUBiGv/9YuhBLkCA08FdogRFFYFEUhhZNCCQoSESiIOii68pl5qV6s8Eb7+SMHXNs6S7ejZ3zvA+ccT4BICofvS88dJ7w8vqG8WQC754K17lPjrx3z3l8D4YoVaqIrWbcJNbzaHefNZjfXPdy5b0jsO/IRqMxUpmSBnhz2bx1QL79GPbpEePmzhdSyW8fBDL0SK68HwiGCT2S3NiKREaPzP7QRRNPZSHpwm4kMnqkYbQikdEjZv8HK2ubS4nY75mD6WU8qzeXkrHvToBlWSjuHC4kYo99V8bwBnM0/iMiz542myq2bSPskcmR/zPos7lvP8Lv/nGd+/N6c2Xq2KcXhiY6qV1rxwotU3n/NHF8fgW+g9hfsHJlJUYljcgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.my-liked, .my-like:hover {
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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) !important;
    height:17px;
    width:19px;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', '<iframe id="my-like-frame" style="display:none;"></iframe>' );
document.addEventListener( 'click', function ( event ) {
    var myLikeLink = event.target;
    if( myLikeLink.className.indexOf( 'my-like' ) > -1 ) {
        var myLikeFrame = document.getElementById( 'my-like-frame' ),
            liked = ( myLikeLink.className == 'my-liked' ),
            command = liked ? 'unlike' : 'like',
            reblog = myLikeLink.getAttribute( 'data-reblog' ),
            postId = myLikeLink.getAttribute( 'data-id' ),
            oauth = reblog.slice( -8 ),
            likeUrl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/' + command + '/' + oauth + '?id=' + postId;
        myLikeFrame.src = likeUrl;
        liked ? myLikeLink.className = 'my-like'
            : myLikeLink.className = 'my-liked';
    };
}, false );
};
</script>
```

Then cut and paste the following button code into your theme where you want your like button to be (this must be inside your `{block:Posts}` block).

```html
<div class="my-like" data-reblog="{ReblogURL}" data-id="{PostID}"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer, so I need something like this for her method (stripped down version for block photo):


`{block:Posts}
{block:Photo}
<div id="{PostID}" rel="{ReblogURL}" class="post">
<img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" width=600px/>
<a href="#" class="like-link">like</a>
</div>
{/block:Photo}
{/block:Posts}



But I'm not sure where the link for the like button is supposed to point? the iframe #likeit? I will try to use your method which has the cool toogle functionality once this one works. What is "ul" and "href" in your method? Your theme rocks.

Comment: @user1148640 The link goes inside the `Posts` block, like you have done. The URL you can just set to `#` because the script is going to take over the link for you.

Comment: Thanks, it is working! And your trick for toggling between like/unlike works too! Many cheers from France!

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure this is working, not even in the Ciceron Theme. I get this error:

`GET http://www.tumblr.com/like/vNQMTLwX?id=7703094650 403 (Forbidden) www.tumblr.com/like/vNQMTLwX?id=7703094650:1
Refused to display 'http://www.tumblr.com/like/vNQMTLwX?id=7703094650' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.`

Those who claims that this works... Did you checked it afterwards?

Comment: @HectorLorenzo This stopped working a few weeks back because Tumblr added Like Buttons to their theme language: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons I need to update this post.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff any progress on getting this to work with the new schema?

Comment: @ThinkingStiff i am getting error in console
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: http://www.tumblr.com/like/iKvmNy9T?id=236 does not permit framing.

Comment: Just to clarify, this method will no longer work with the new Like / Reblog buttons.