# Tumblr Like api on a non-tumblr url

Tags: javascript, api, tumblr

As far as I understand, the previously working method for 'liking' posts through tumblr's api is no longer working.

Reference: [heart (like) button on tumblr homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858323/heart-like-button-on-tumblr-homepage)

I have attempted both, the old method described in the latter post and also embedding the iframe method seemingly used after tumblr parses stuff internally. Both methods return 403 Forbidden.

Is it at all possible to like a post using the new api spec outside of the tumblr platform?

What alternative avenues can I take to implement this?

Comment: Afaik, the only method to liking posts (outside of the custom html stuff) is using the API. The previous methods, as you mentioned, have been removed in favour of using the API.

Comment: API v2, that is. API v1 offers a like button in their JSON object, but this button does not seem to register likes, there's a large structure of postMessage's and receiveMessage's missing.